# Not complex differentiable function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, cauchy-riemann-equations

Define $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as

$f(z):= \begin{cases}\exp(-z^{-4}), &x \ne 0\\ 0, &x=0.\end{cases}$

Show that $F(x_1,x_2):=(\text{Re}(f(x_1+ix_2)),\text{Im}(f(x_1+ix_2)))$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but it's not complex differentiable

I think I have to expand the term $e^{(-(x+iy)^{-4})}$ to find the real and imaginary part of the function. But I'm having problems trying to do so. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: First, note that $(x+iy)^4 = (x^4 -6x^2y^2+y^4)+(4x^3y-4xy^3)i$ and so $(x+iy)^{-4}= \frac{1}{(x^4 -6x^2y^2+y^4)+(4x^3y-4xy^3)i}$. You can then multiply by $\frac{(x^4 -6x^2y^2+y^4)-(4x^3y-4xy^3)i}{(x^4 -6x^2y^2+y^4)-(4x^3y-4xy^3)i}$ and expand to get something of the form $e^{a+bi}$ for real $a$ and $b$. After that, you can use Euler's identity.

Comment: I found this problem easier (as in you dont need to expand) if you consider z=x+yi and re(f(z))= f(z) + \bar{f(z)} /2 ,im(f(z))= f(z) - \bar{f(z)} /2i